# I want to use an argument from the path in a twig template (as a html class)

Tags: 8, uri, theming

Having read about how D8's path system is different from D7, and having seen some 'simple' examples, I have tried

- setting a path variable in a preprocess functions and outputting that as a {{ my_path_variable }} in a twig template
- outputting {{ kint(my_path_variable) }} in the twig template
- outputting kint(my_path_variable) in the preprocess function

None of the above works, I only get NULL in my kint output.

I've read this page: [Get the current path alias or path?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106103/get-current-alias-or-path-in-drupal-8), and I really don't know where I'm supposed to place the $current_path definition in order to get the path into a twig template, so I can output it as variable.

Comment: #1 is the correct solution. If it is not showing up(and you cleared cache) then you most likely have wrong value to begin with.

Comment: See [How can I dynamically add URL or taxonomy to body class](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188200/how-can-i-dynamically-add-url-or-taxonomy-to-body-class/188363#188363)