# Add the user role to the body class

Tags: theming, 8

How do you add the class of the user role to the body tag, say in `html.html.twig`, in much the same way as you can add the path in [How can I dynamically add URL or taxonomy to body class](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188200/how-can-i-dynamically-add-url-or-taxonomy-to-body-class)?

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you could achieve that:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  // The getRoles() method will return us the machine names, so there is no
  // need to process roles names additionally. However, I suggest prefixing
  // the names with "role-", so it's more obvious.
  foreach ($variables['user']->getRoles() as $role) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'role-' . $role;
  }
}
```

Then in your `html.html.twig` file you can set the attributes this way:

```
<body{{ attributes }}>
```

Note: you might want to pass `TRUE` to the `getRoles()` method, if you want to exclude the locked roles (anonymous and authenticated). You can read the docs on this method [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AgetRoles/8).

Comment: I can confirm this works. Thanks! Just to clarify for other users, I am able to leave my body tag with the original setting (from Classy) as <body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }} >.

Comment: Glad it helped. If this solved your question, mark this answer as the solution, so others with the same question know this is what they're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Roles Classes](https://www.drupal.org/project/body_roles_classes) module (works for the admin theme)