# How can I add a single taxonomy term label as a body class?

Tags: theming

I'd like to add a single taxonomy term into the body tag as a class in drupal 8 - so I page styles can be controlled easily.
I have tried (path and ID as class in body [How can I dynamically add URL or taxonomy to body class](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188200/how-can-i-dynamically-add-url-or-taxonomy-to-body-class) and https://www.drupal.org/node/2634364) which only get me part way there, taxonomy term would provide a future proofed solution.

Answer (score 4):

i found a solution which worked perfectly for me. Add this in your .theme file and replace **mytheme**_preprocess_html by your theme name and field_section by name of your taxonomy field.

[https://gist.github.com/awasson/d8ef8d7c1b64b2ccb8a0][1]

```
<?php

    /**
     * Prepares variables for the html.html.twig template.
     */

    use Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
    use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;

    function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

      if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {

        /**
         * Get the term id from the 'field_section' taxonomy field.
         * If greater than zero, load the term and acquire the name value 
         * as a css safe value.
        */
        if($node->hasField('field_section')) {
          $tid = $node->get('field_section')->target_id;
          if($tid > 0) {
            $term_object = Term::load($tid);
            $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'terms--' . Html::getClass($term_object->get('name')->value);
          }
        }

        /**
         * Get the node id from the node object.
         * If greater than zero, add the node id to body classes  
        */
        $nid = $node->get('nid')->value;
        if($nid > 0) {
          $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'page--node-' . $nid;
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is my snippet for `field_razdel` with transliteration (as my site is not english).
Finally I have these body classes (other elements are added with another piece of code):

```
  <body class="no-sidebars terms--obrazovanie path-node page-node-type-article">
```

**terms--obrazovanie** is added by next snippet:

```
// Add taxonomy term from field_razdel as body class.
if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) { 
  // Get the term id from the 'field_section' taxonomy field.
  // If greater than zero, load the term and acquire the name value 
  // as a css safe value.
  // Use the current default interface language.
  $langcode = \Drupal::languageManager()
    ->getCurrentLanguage()
    ->getId();

  // Instantiate the transliteration class.
  $trans = \Drupal::transliteration();

  if ($node->hasField('field_razdel')) {
    $tid = $node->get('field_razdel')->target_id;
    if ($tid > 0) {
      $term_object = Term::load($tid);
      //$variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'terms--' . Html::getClass($term_object->get('name')->value);
      $transformed = $trans
        ->transliterate(Html::getClass($term_object->get('name')->value), $langcode);
      $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'terms--' . $transformed;
    }
  }
}
```