# Add a taxonomy ID class to the body tag

Tags: theming, 8, taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy vocabulary whose various parents and children need to have different styles. I would need the tid of the every taxonomy page to appear as a class in the body tag in order to make CSS selectors.

I tried using [How can I dynamically add URL or taxonomy to body class](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188200/how-can-i-dynamically-add-url-or-taxonomy-to-body-class)
to work out a solution, but it seems to work only for nodes. I get a class called path-taxonomy for every taxonomy term and that's it.

I would prefer not to install any module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked example gets the path. Here better use routing. Check the name of the matched route and then get a parameter which is defined in the route. Normally you use `getParameter()` to get the loaded entity, in this case it's `getRawParameter()` for the id:

*mytheme.theme:*

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'entity.taxonomy_term.canonical') {
    $variables['term_id'] = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('taxonomy_term');
  }
}
```

*html.html.twig:*

```
{%
  set body_classes = [
    term_id ? 'term-id-' ~ term_id,
  ]
%}
<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks. At first I had huge problems with the changes not wanting to take effect, I spent literally an entire day clearing caches, setting up twig, and the changes appeared only this morning, just as I was thinking there was no more hope for my site.